# Problem with my trained recognition image model, how to keep it and not have it replaced by the base model

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, image-recognition

I have a problem with my code. The goal is to create a model and train it, the problem is that my trained model = previous, I can't use it for my analysis with previous.predict for example. Do you know how to do this?

```
def create_model(image_size=224):
    # Generate a model with all layers (without top)
    pre_trained_model = VGG16(input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    
    # Freeze the layers except the last 2 layers
    for layer in pre_trained_model.layers[:-2]:
        layer.trainable = False
        
    # Add the layers specified in the question
    model = Sequential([
        pre_trained_model,
        Flatten(),
        Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

```
model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

```
Previous = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(img_data_train) // train_generator.batch_size,
                    epochs=3,
                    validation_data=test_generator,
                    validation_steps=len(img_data_test) // test_generator.batch_size)
```

````
y_pred = model.predict(test_generator)
y_pred_classes = (y_pred > 0.5).astype(int)
print(classification_report(test_labels, y_pred_classes))```




I've tried many things but nothing works.
````